# How to specify the data to be inserted in the ArcGIS Server REST API's Append function?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, append

I have a feature layer that is hosted in ArcGIS Server 10.71 and I would like to insert new data into this layer using the ArcGIS Server REST API's [Append](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/append-feature-service-layer-.htm#) function.

As shown by the `appendUploadFormat` parameter, this function supports a variety of formats including shapefile, geodatabase, Excel, etc.

However, I can't see where to actually upload the input dataset - eg there is no "file upload" capability offered by this function.

The `appendSourceInfo` parameter mentions a `sourceUrl` sub-parameter, which looks promising as it implies that I can upload the file then reference it by location. But the `sourceUrl` parameter is not documented in depth, and the `appendSourceInfo` parameter itself is listed as "only needed when appending data from Excel or CSV".

As an example, how do I tell the Append function where to find an input shapefile that I wish to append to the target feature layer?

Comment: Without testing, I *think* you need to do an `addItem`, uploading the file you'll be using to append as a **new item**. Then, the params you have in question for `append` reference that item. The easiest way to verify this is use arcgis.com with the dev tools open and watch the network requests. you'll see the pattern.

Comment: @KHibma many thanks, this looks promising. This also implies that ArcGIS Online or Portal for ArcGIS are involved. I'll report back on how it goes

Comment: Ohhh! You aren't working with Portal or Online? Then you may want to look at the `uploads` endpoint on the featureservice. See the doc/examples here: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/upload.htm

Comment: @KHibma see my related question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372221/how-to-enable-supportsappend-on-a-feature-layer-in-arcgis-server - thanks in advance for any tips :)